# Rewriting a boolean expression in SOP form

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

I have started a discrete math module for my computer science course and I'm having a little trouble using the identity, idempotent and complement laws to convert a boolean expression into sum of products (SOP) form.

$F(x,y,z) = (x+y')*z$
$=(z*x)+(z*y')$
$=(z+z)*(z+y')*(z+x)*(x+y')$

This is where I'm stuck. I could simplify it but I am not sure how to get to $(x'y'z)+(xy'z)+(xyz)$ that i got with a truth table.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards, Luke

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g*., [basic help on mathjax notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), [main meta site math tutorial](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68388/there-should-be-universal-latex-mathjax-guide-for-sites-supporting-it/70559#70559), and [equation editing how-to](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto).

Comment: Your first step, distributing $z$ over $x+y'$, gives you a sum of products.  I'm not sure what to make of the next line.  Is it a new problem?  It doesn't seem to have any relationship to the line above it.

Comment: @hardmath using De Morgan's law twice and distributive law once, $zx+zy'=(zx+zy')''=((z'+x')(z'+y))'=(z'z'+z'y+x'z'+x'y)'=(z+z)(z+y')(x+z)(x+y')$

Comment: @hardmath it's the distributive law where the 'plus' distributes over the 'times'.

Answer (score 1):

After your first step you have $(z*x)+(z*y')$. That is in SOP, so you are done!

Answer (score 0):

first find $x+y'$ in SOP form.
$x+y'=x(y+y')+y'(x+x')$
$=xy+xy'+xy'+x'y'$
$=xy+xy'+x'y'$

multiply both sides by $z$.
$(x+y')z=(xy+xy'+x'y')z$
$=xyz+xy'z+x'y'z$

Comment: Thanks @cineel. As im still learning the laws, could i ask if im right in thinking what xou did was use distributive with complement law to expand the (x+y'), then idempotent to remove one of the + xy'. Then used distriutive factorising to re introduce the z? im not sure if that is right and where i could use the identity law?

Comment: @lukemason x=x*1=x*(y+y') the first step uses identity law and the second step uses complement law.